# How were Blaschke factors discovered?

Tags: complex-analysis

The map

$$\psi_\alpha(z) = \frac{\alpha - z}{1 - \overline{\alpha}z}$$

can be shown to be a conformal map from the disc onto itself that interchanges $\alpha$ and $0$. I understand how to prove this in a few ways, although I'm a little bewildered at how one would guess this function $\psi_a$ in the first place. If I wanted an automorphism of the disc that interchanged $\alpha$ and $0$, how would I have thought of the above function?

Comment: Last calculation in the answer in more detail, comes from: $\begin{align}1&=|f(z)|^2\\&=\frac{|\alpha-z|^2}{|1+cz|^2}\\\Rightarrow |\alpha-z|^2&=|1+cz|^2\\ (\alpha-z)\overline{\alpha-z}&=(1+cz)\overline{1+cz}\\(\alpha-z)(\bar\alpha-\bar z)&=(1+cz)(1+\bar c\bar z)\\\overset{|z|=1}{\Rightarrow}(\alpha-z)\left(\bar\alpha-\frac1z\right)&=(1+cz)\left(1+\frac{\bar c}z\right)\end{align}$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start from the fact that every automorphism of the Riemann sphere has the form $f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$ (we'll tack on the requirement that $f$ sends the disc to itself later). To send $0$ to $\alpha$ we need $\frac{b}{d} = \alpha$ so we might as well set $b = \alpha, d = 1$. To send $\alpha$ to $0$ we need $\frac{a \alpha + \alpha}{c \alpha + 1} = 0$, so $a = -1$ and $c \neq \frac{1}{\alpha}$. So far we know that we must have
$$f(z) = \frac{\alpha - z}{1 + cz}$$

for some $c$. Now we want this map to restrict to an automorphism of the open disc. This implies that $f$ must in fact preserve the unit circle: if $|z| = 1$ but $|f(z)| > 1$ then by moving $z$ into the open disc we get that $f$ doesn't send the open disc to itself, and if $|f(z)| < 1$ then by a similar argument we get that $f^{-1}$ doesn't send the open disc to itself.

This is a strong condition: we now know that $|z| = 1$ implies $|f(z)| = 1$. When $|z| = 1$ we have that $\bar{z} = \frac{1}{z}$, so setting $|f(z)|^2 = 1$ (remembering that $|w|^2 = w \bar{w}$) we conclude that
$$\left( \alpha - z \right) \left( \bar{\alpha} - \frac{1}{z} \right) = |\alpha|^2 - \bar{\alpha} z - \frac{\alpha}{z} + 1 = \left( 1 + cz \right) \left( 1 + \frac{\bar{c}}{z} \right) = 1 + cz + \frac{\bar{c}}{z} + |c|^2$$

and equating coefficients of $z$ gives $c = - \bar{\alpha}$ as desired.

Comment: This process helped me solve a problem from Lars Ahlfors complex analysis. What is the most general transformation sending the circle $|z|=2$ into $|z+1|=1$ and sending $-2$ to $0$ and $0$ to $i$.